# Magento 2.4.3 Using \Laminas\Log\Logger::WARN or EMERG, DEBUG not working anymore

Tags: laminas, magento2.4.3

I have implemented the plugin which uses some constants of `\Laminas\Log\Logger::WARN`

`di.xml`

```
 <type name="Magento\Elasticsearch\SearchAdapter\ResponseFactory">
        <plugin name="Custom_Es::debugRawResponse"
                type="Custom\Es\Plugin\ResponseCheck"
                disabled="false"/>
</type>
```

`ResponseCheck.php`

```
<?php
namespace Custom\Es\Plugin;

use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

/**
 * Response Factory
 * @api
 * @since 100.1.0
 */
class ResponseCheck
{
    /**
     * Psr Logger  instance
     *
     * @var LoggerInterface
     * @since 100.1.0
     */
    protected $logger;


    /**
     * @param ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        LoggerInterface $logger
    )
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;

    }


    public function beforeCreate(\Magento\Elasticsearch\SearchAdapter\ResponseFactory $subject, $result)
    {
        $docRaw = $docRawScore = array();
        /*$writer = new \Laminas\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/ESResponse.log');
        $logger = new \Laminas\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);*/
        
        $warn = \Laminas\Log\Logger::WARN;
        if (!is_array($result) || empty($result)) return false;


    }

}
```

Which leads me to following error:

`Error: Class 'Laminas\Log\Logger' not found in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/Custom/Es/Plugin/ResponseCheck.php:42`

Even `new \Laminas\Log\Writer\Stream(BP .'/var/log/ESResponse.log');` is also not working.

Comment: https://techurbane.com/how-to-add-custom-logs-in-magento-2/

Answer (score 2):

In Magento 2.4.3, we need to use below code scippet to the log in the custom file.

```
$writer = new \Zend_Log_Writer_Stream(BP . '/var/log/customfile.log');
$logger = new \Zend_Log();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$logger->info('I am logged');
$logger->info('Array Log'.print_r($myArray, true));
```

This code is pretty self-explanatory. It will create a log file named customfile.log under var/log/ folder and log ‘I am logged’ in it.

To print array use: $logger->info('Array Log'.print_r($myArray, true));

Answer (score 1):

In Magento 2.4.3 remove Laminas\Log\ so you need to add

> ```
> \Zend_Log::INFO
> ```

$warn = \Zend_Log::WARN;
if (!is_array($result) || empty($result)) return false;